# Unable to send at sign or curly braces using C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

Basically I want to put the following text into an HTML `input` field: `{mail@example.com}`.

Unfortunately: `elem.SendKeys("{mail@example.com}")` results in `7mailqexample.com0`.

On my German keyboard layout, 7, q and 0 correspond to the correct keys, however, it looks like the API does not send the AltGr key beforehand. I've read that there are problems with different keyboard layouts, which is why I also tested the following code:

```
elem.SendKeys (Keys.LeftAlt + "Q"); // Is LeftAlt the "normal" Alt?
elem.SendKeys (Keys.Alt + "Q"); // Alt is AltGr? 
elem.SendKeys (Keys.LeftAlt + "2"); // Try also to type '@' with English layout
elem.SendKeys (Keys.Alt + "2");
```

Unfortunately those four calls result in an empty input control.

What's the solution?

Side note: this happens using InternetExplorerDriver (I'm using the 32bit driver) only (native events are enabled). The ChromeDriver is able to work with `elem.SendKeys("@")` perfectly...

Another side note: is it possible that this is a bug in the IEDriver implementation? When using the following snippet instead:

```
new Actions(webDriver).MoveToElement(elem).Click().Perform(); // Focus input element
SendKeys.SendWait("@");
```

It works...however, this doesn't look like the right way...

Comment: I've seen solutions using `Keys.chord()` in Java - which seems to not exist in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into an issue with `InternetExplorerDriver` [I've reported](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6540) nearly a year ago.

To quote myself from the issue:

> When using native events while require window focus is set to true,
>   IE-Driver will use SendInput rather than SendMessage API (according to
>   http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html)
>
> It seems that IE Driver looks for the keyboard combination with the
>   setted keyboard layout (German), but inputs this combination with an
>   English keyboard layout, or something like that.

Possible workarounds:

- Using an English keyboard layout
- Setting requireWindowFocus to false (haven't tried that one myself)
- comment and star my reported issue; maybe it will get fixed soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Try
    Key.OemCloseBrackets
or 
    Key.OemOpenBrackets

Comment: Those are not even usable as parameters for `SendKeys.Send()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in Software and Quality Assurance Stackexchange site, [How can I send the action “Ctrl” + “Alt” + “Double Click” to the browser](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/how-can-i-send-the-action-ctrl-alt-double-click-to-the-browser)

Basically you have to create an `Actions` object, add the desired key functionality, `KeyUp` all the pressed keys, and at last `Perfom()` the actions.

Working with english keyboard configuration you'll have to:

```
var actions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(driver);
actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Alt);
actions.SendKeys("2"); // '@' char
//actions.SendKeys("]"); // '}´ çhar
actions.KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.Alt);
actions.Build().Perform();
```